# Printing B+ tree in C

Tags: c, b-tree

I have implemented `B+` tree in `C` and wants to print its keys in the tree form. I followed the following algorithms for printing it but getting some segmentation fault.

1. Starting from root, first of all queuing it. Then dequeing until the queue becomes nil.
2. As each node contains both keys and their values(pointers to next level nodes), each of those values are also queued while reaching the particular node.

Following is the code for queuing,dequeuing and printing the leaf. Please let me know what is wrong with this partcularcode.

```
           typedef struct QUEUE{
            BPLUS bplusNode;
            struct QUEUE * next;
                    }*ENQUEUE;
```

Following  code is to queue the nodes of tree.(I am going to implement Breadth first search)

```
      void bplus_Enqueue(BPLUS bplusNew){
          ENQUEUE bplusTemp;
          if (queue == NULL){
          queue = (ENQUEUE)malloc(sizeof(ENQUEUE));
          queue->bplusNode= bplusNew;
          queue->next = NULL;
              }
               else {
               bplusTemp = (ENQUEUE)malloc(sizeof(ENQUEUE));
               bplusTemp->bplusNode = bplusNew;
               bplusTemp->next = NULL;
        while(queue->next != NULL) {
                queue = queue->next;
                      }
                queue->next = bplusTemp;
                free(bplusTemp);
                   }
             }
```

Following code is for dequeuing

```
          BPLUS bplus_Dequeue( void ){
          BPLUS bplusTemp = queue->bplusNode;
          queue = queue->next;
          return bplusTemp;
           }
```

Following code is for printing the tree.

```
   void  bplus_PrintBplus(BPLUS root){
   int i;
   BPLUS tempBplus;
   queue = NULL;
   bplus_Enqueue(root);
   if(queue == NULL){
     printf("Sala kaam garena\n");
    }
   while(queue != NULL){
   tempBplus = bplus_Dequeue();
          for(i=0;i<tempBplus->numKeys;i++){
          printf("%d -----> %d\n",i,tempBplus->keys[i]);
             }
          if(tempBplus->next != NULL){
             for(i=0;i<=tempBplus->numKeys;i++)
           bplus_Enqueue(tempBplus->pointers[i]);
            }
        }
    }
```

This code prints the key value of `root` and first successive node of root and then gets segmentation fault. Could you please help me to figure out what is wrong with this code?

Comment: How is variable queue accessible in different functions ? Static or passed as an argument ?

Comment: You're getting **some** segmentation fault? Could you at least spend 15 minutes in a debugger to get more specific information?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't checked the full code, but these parts are really weird:

```
bplusTemp->bplusNode = bplusNode;
```

What's bplusNode here? Haven't seen its declaration.

```
queue->next = bplusTemp;
free(bplusTemp);
```

this is just plain nuts :)

Comment: sorry that was a typo mistake. I corrected it, in place of **=bplusNode**,its **bplusNew**,that is incomming **BPLUS** tree node.

Answer (score 1):

Level order traversal is done through two queues, one for accessing elements in the current level and the other one for building the queue for next level. I have successfully implemented this for Binary Search Tree. You can use the same logic for B+ trees.

```
void BinarySearchTree::printLevelBased()
{
    Queue<Node *> *nodeQueue1 = new Queue<Node *>();
    Queue<Node *> *nodeQueue2 = new Queue<Node *>();;
    Node *currentNode;
    int numOfLevels = 0;

    nodeQueue1->put(mRoot);

    while(false == nodeQueue1->isEmpty())
    {
        numOfLevels++;
        Queue<Node *> *temp = nodeQueue1;
        nodeQueue1 = nodeQueue2;
        nodeQueue2 = temp;

        while(false == nodeQueue2->isEmpty())
        {
            currentNode = nodeQueue2->get(); // Dequeue
            PRINT_NODE_DATA(currentNode);
            if(currentNode->hasLeft())
            {
                nodeQueue1->put(currentNode->mLeft); // Enqueue
            }
            if(currentNode->hasRight())
            {
                nodeQueue1->put(currentNode->mRight);
            }
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    return;
}
```

Shash

Comment: You should be able to-do level-order traversal with only one queue.  You simply pop an node off the front of the queue, and push each nodes's child onto the back of the queue.

Answer (score 1):

This line of code looks odd in your `bplus_Enqueue` function:

```
queue->next = bplusTemp;
free(bplusTemp);
```

basically you are setting the next node in the linked-list you're using for your queue, but then freeing it after assigning the `next` pointer to the previous end of the linked list.  That is going to mean that your next-to-last node is pointing to freed memory rather than a valid linked-list node, which will cause a segmentation fault when it's accessed.  The memory being pointed to by `bplusTemp` node, after the first line, is now "owned" by the list ... you can't call `free` on that pointer, or else every other pointer that points to that memory (in this case `queue->next`) is also pointing to freed memory and will segfault when it tries to access that memory.

This would also make sense on why you are able to print the first two node values (root, and one of its children), and then get a segfault.  Basically you never call those lines when the queue is empty, and you're adding the first node.  So when you add `root`, you're okay ... you don't call `free` on it.  You then dequeue it, and when you do that, the queue is empty again.  So the next child of `root` is added to the queue, and that again is fine, since because the queue was empty, you don not call `free` on `bplusNew`.  But now when you add any other children of the root, and the queue is not empty, you end up calling `free` on `bplusNew`, causing you queue to only contain a single value value.  In other words the first node being pointed to by `queue->next` (i.e., the second node in the linked list), is actually not accessible anymore ... you've called `free` on that memory.

Secondly, in your `bplus_Dequeue` function you have a memory leak ... specifically here:

```
BPLUS bplusTemp = queue->bplusNode;
queue = queue->next;
```

You're re-assigning the front of the linked-list without freeing the node that was the original head of the list.  Now you don't have a pointer to that node anymore, and it's considered leaked memory.

Comment: I also realized that there is problem in dequeuing. Could you help me how can I make it error free?

Comment: Because of the design of your queue, you can't simply free the queue node when you do the dequeue operation ... that would again cause a segmentation fault as the `BPLUS` pointer would be pointing to freed memory.  So I would recommend a two-stage process where one function simply returns the front element to the queue, and the second function actual removes the node from the queue.  This would be similar to how `std::queue::front()` and `std::queue::pop()` work together.

Comment: So in your code, you would call the `front()` function to get the `BPLUS` pointer on the front of the queue.  Once you have completed using that pointer, you would then call `pop()` to remove the node from the front of the queue.  Keep in mind that after the call to `pop`, since the queue is actually the owner of the memory pointed to by `BPLUS`, that returned pointer will not be valid anymore, so you must take care to not dereference the returned `BPLUS` pointer from the front of the queue after you've called your queue `pop()` function.